# AngularJS - Material Design | Can $mdBottomSheet be placed over $mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am currently working on a calendar UI and I am trying to make an $mdBottomSheet appear over an already open $mdDialog.  Is there a way to change the placement of the layer, kind of like a z-index through stylesheets?

*Here is what I an trying to do*:[image]

[image: What I have currently]

Comment: Or be able to bring up a Bottom sheet within the mdDialog?

Comment: Can't you use a normal footer?

Comment: @nextt1 the $mdBottomSheet slides up from the bottom when a day in the calendar is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$mdDialog` has a `z-index` of 80, and the `$mdBottomSheet` has a `z-index` equal 70.
By just including this in your stylesheet

```
md-bottom-sheet{
   z-index: 81;
}
```

should work.